# Changing background of main div when hovering over subdiv

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover, mouseout

I have 1 container with 3 sub items and Jquery:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.sub1').hover(function() {
    $('#container').css('background-image', 'url("../img/plan.jpg")');
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background colour
    $('#container').css('background-color', '');
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="sub1">This is link 1</div>
  <div class="sub2">This is link 2</div>
  <div class="sub3">This is link 3</div>
</div>
```

The goal is to change the background of "container" when hovering over "sub1", "sub2" or "sub3". Each sub has it's own background-image in css. Once mouse is not longer hovering "sub1", "sub2" or "sub3" the background will return to white.

Dont mind that theres no sub2 or sub3 functions yet, I focus on those later.

I got it working till the part of mouseout. The container background wont return to it's original state (white).

Is there some guru that can help me out?

Thanks in advance,

Roelof!

Comment: Shouldn't you reset the `background-image` property instead of the `background-color`?

Comment: look at this sample http://jsbin.com/umalu4/edit?html,js,output

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve here, what is it supposed to look like? And what does it represent, a navigation menu of some sorts? Wonder if this could not perhaps be solved using CSS alone.

Comment: Look at http://roelofplas.nl/#about by the way I used id's like container and classes like sub1 sub 2 sub 3 etc just to make it easier to read for you guys. My code is a mess most of the time haha. (Btw, I'm editting that site to learn from it, I did not make it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are resetting background-color instead of background-image. I took the liberty of making it work for all subs too. :)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').on('mouseover', '[class^="sub"]', function() {
    var container = $('#container');
    switch ($(this).attr('class')) {
      case 'sub1':
        container.css('background-image', 'url("http://placehold.it/500x50")');
        break;
      case 'sub2':
        container.css('background-image', 'url("http://placehold.it/500x60")');
        break;
      case 'sub3':
        container.css('background-image', 'url("http://placehold.it/500x70")');
        break;
      default:
    }
  });
  
  $('#container').on('mouseout', '[class^="sub"]', function() {
    $('#container').css('background-image', '');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="sub1">This is link 1</div>
  <div class="sub2">This is link 2</div>
  <div class="sub3">This is link 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have to say thank you aswell, because that thing u pulled off with the subs got me curious. I will look into this for sure once I got this whole thing working. :D

Comment: You're welcome, and best of luck. Short explanation: `[class^="sub"]` targets all classes which starts with "sub", but in this setup only if inside `#container`. `$(this).attr('class')` gets the full class name for the switch-statement. The rest I guess you understand. :)

Comment: After your edit I use this code instead. This is excactly what I ment.
Look at http://www.roelofplas.nl/#about to see it working. I used diffrent id in my question to make it easier. But it works like I wanted it now.

Any idea how I can make the "box" bigger where the mouse triggers the mousin / mouse out?

Comment: Yes, perhaps the CSS `.howitworks li { display: block; }` will do the trick?

Comment: Yes that kind of did it indeed. Now I'm trying to add a fade to the background mousein mouseout. Any idea how I should adress that?

Answer (score 3):

I think the only error in your code is that you reset the `background-color` instead of the `background-image` property

```
$(function() {
 $('.sub1').hover(function() { 
   $('#container').css('background-image', 'url("../img/plan.jpg")');
 }, function() {
   // on mouseout, reset the background colour
   $('#container').css('background-image', ''); // definately here is the error
 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this reply and market it as awnser. Thanks a lot. I'm so stupid sometimes lol. :)

Answer (score 2):

It should look like that when hover over every `.sub` you get color red other wise you get green 
And then you can just put image into it

**EDITED:**
Add image for you on hover you get image on mouse out you get image remove and set color

```js
   $(function() {
      $('#container > div').hover(function() {
        $('#container').css('background-image',                   'url(http://www.placecage.com/200/300)');
        console.log("mouse over");
      }, function() {
        // on mouseover, reset the background colour
        $('#container').css({
           'background-color': 'green',
           'background-image': 'none'
        });
        console.log("mouse out");
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="container">
      <div class="sub1">This is link 1</div>
      <div class="sub2">This is link 2</div>
      <div class="sub3">This is link 3</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are right, I had background-color instead of background-image. I love being noob in coding haha. -.-

Comment: no problem bro :) we are all learning every day, have a nice coding in future :)